# Days between dates in DayJS UK Format

Tags: javascript, dayjs

Im using dayjs, and I'm trying to calculate the days between 2 days so that I can output `Today`, `Tomorrow` and `X days time`

The problem I'm having though seems to be with the date formats

```
const date1 = dayjs('31/10/2021');
const date2 = dayjs().format("DD/MM/YYYY")

let hours = date2.diff(date1, 'days')
```

No matter how I try, I'm getting `date2.diff is not a function` when I add `.format` to date2.  Does anyone know how to format this correctly and get the correct outcome?

If i try `const date1 = dayjs('31/10/2021').format("DD/MM/YYYY");` then it errors with invalid date

Comment: Have you tried using momentJs, their API is somewhat similar.

Comment: I have, but want to use dayjs as its a lot more lightweight, and dont need to added functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
const date1 = dayjs('2021-01-25');
const date2 = '01/11/2020'; // or '2020-11-01'

let hours = date1.diff(date2, 'day')

console.log(hours) // 380
```

The `format` function just returns a string. This is why `date2.diff` is not a function.
The `diff` function is only available for `dayjs` objects (not for strings).

Docs for `difference` function: https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference

Docs for `format` function: https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format

Answer (score 0):

```
const date1 = dayjs('2019-01-25')
date1.diff('2018-06-05', 'day', true)
```

You don't need to call format function, just use dayjs constructor to convert both dates to dayjs object and return the difference between the 2 dates in number of days.